# How to know when user document loaded in Meteor Accounts

Tags: meteor

I understand that when writing code that depends on the collection being loaded into the client minimongo, that you should explicitly subscribe to the collection and pass in the appropriate callback for when it is finished loading.

My problem is that I store a lot of important subdocuments that my page needs to access in the users collection. I am using Meteor Accounts, and am trying to figure out a similar way to wait until the entire logged in user document is available. When using this to test:

```
console.log(Meteor.user());
```

the logged in case, it seems like it first registers an object with just the _id, and then sends the other fields later (I know I have to explicitly add other fields to publish from the server beyond email, etc.).

Is there a way for me to wait for the logged in user document to load completely before executing my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deps.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun) (previously Meteor.autorun) reruns when something reactive changes, which might fit your use case:

**Client js**

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if(Meteor.user() {
          //Collection available
      }
    });
```

If you're using a [subscription](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) you can also use its callback. Have a read about it on the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) as you might have to customize it a bit, and remove the autopublish package as well as get your other collections set up to subscriptions

**Server js:**

```
Meteor.publish("userdata", function () {
    //You might want to alter this depending on what you want to send down
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {}});
});
```

**Client js**

```
Meteor.subscribe("userdata", function() {
    //Collection available
});
```

Comment: Definitely alter the above publish function, as the way it is currently written will publish all user data to all users, which is both a major security hole as well as terrible performance.

Comment: This is why I said it needs to be altered to send down the fields you want.